# Refreshing page on a back button in angular/ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to refresh the page on the back button to get the new data for article list. To be more specific I have an article list, and the article page, on both of them I have an option of liking an article. When a user likes an article on the article page, if it hits the back button the like icon on the article list page won't get refreshed with the new state. I have tried with making a function on clicking the back button, and then getting the data again, but the icon doesn't change. The data that I get on `console.log` is new data and I get the value for `like=1` which is correct if the user has liked the article, but the icon doesn't change.
This is my code:

I get the articles like this in my front page controller:

```
ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
  })
```

In my article page html I have a back button link:

```
<a ng-click="refresh()"></a>
```

And in my article list I check which value I have for like and then show the icon according to that:

```
<a ng-if="article.like == 1" ng-click="like(article)" class="subdued">
              <img class="social-images" src="icons/heart.svg"/> Lik
            </a>
            <a ng-if="article.like == 0" ng-click="like(article)" class="subdued">
              <img class="social-images" src="icons/heart-outline.svg"/> Lik
            </a>
```

This is my function in the article controller:

```
$scope.refresh = function (){
    return $state.go('main.front').then(function(state) {
      ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
        $scope.articles = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
    })
  };
```

But since that function is in the article controller it cannot refresh the data on the front page. How can I refresh the data in the front page controller from the page that has a different controller?

Comment: Please provide a codepen example.

Comment: It is ionic cache issue.

Comment: @Ved no, I just don't know how to call a function from another controller, I am new to angular so not sure how to do that

Comment: You can call other controller function via $broadcast or $emit. You can also add listener like $staechangeScuccess on controller, to call method on state change

Comment: could you give me an example with some code please, if it is not a problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

1.

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
           $scope.refresh();
        });

$scope.refresh = function (){
        return $state.go('main.front').then(function(state) {
          ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
            $scope.articles = data;
            console.log(data);
          })
        })
      };
```

2.

```
 $scope.$on('$tateChangeSuccess', function () {
           $scope.refresh();
        });
```

3. It may be cache issue. So add,

> ```
> <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
>   </ion-view>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

try adding `cache : false` in your state to reload the state on enter ...

Comment: how to do this in ionic4 & angular7?